# Unnecessary array wrapper

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am stumbling on something annoying and hope you can shed some light. I am generating an array via PHP MySQL query. My WHILE statement is as follows:

```
$model[constraints][d][] = array($row['Node'] => array("max" => $row['dem'], "min"=> $row['dem']));
```

The problem is that each new array added to $model[constraints][d] gets enclosed by an array. See screenshot below:

[image]

I don't want there to be array "0" around Norway. I would like to be able to access my values as follows:

```
$model[constraints][s][Norway][max]
```

Right now, the only way I can access that value is by doing the following:

```
$model[constraints][s][0][Norway][max]
```

How should I amend my while statement to get the desired array? Thank you for your time.

Comment: `$model[constraints][d] = array($row['Node'] => array("max" => $row['dem'], "min"=> $row['dem']));`.... and hope that there's only ever a single entry returned by your database query..... or `$model[constraints][d][$row['Node']] = array("max" => $row['dem'], "min"=> $row['dem']));`

Comment: Hello Mark -no there are 30 entries returned by the DB query. Let me try your second suggestion.

Comment: Genius -that's exactly what I needed. Would you like to provide this as an answer? I will accept the solution. Thank you Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the loop you could do:

```
$model[constraints][d] = array();
```

And then just change the statement inside the loop to:

```
$model[constraints][d] += array($row['Node'] => array("max" => $row['dem'], "min"=> $row['dem']));
```

[Here's a live demo](http://phpepl.cloudcontrolled.com?code=%24model%5B'constraints'%5D%5B'd'%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%24model%5B'constraints'%5D%5B'd'%5D%20%2B%3D%20array('Norway'%20%3D%3E%20array(%22max%22%20%3D%3E%20'12.00'%2C%20%22min%22%3D%3E%20'0'))%3B%0D%0A%24model%5B'constraints'%5D%5B'd'%5D%20%2B%3D%20array('Malasia'%20%3D%3E%20array(%22max%22%20%3D%3E%20'12.00'%2C%20%22min%22%3D%3E%20'0'))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aecho%20json_encode(%24model%5B'constraints'%5D%5B'd'%5D%5B'Norway'%5D)%3B)